# ABFRealmMapView delegate confusion

Tags: delegates, mkmapview, realm

Working with iOS-v9.1, XCode-v7.1 :

The delegation method of my mapView is not yet working.

The following applies:

- mapView property is of type ABFRealmMapView
  [image]
- ABFRealmMapView is a class that inherits from MKMapView
  [image]
- ABFRealmMapView has an externalDelegate definition as follows:
  [image]
- when a map-overlay takes place the renderForOverlay delegation-method is executed correctly:
  [image]
- the idea is that this implementation also calls the delegation-method "renderForOverlay" of the parent-class PVParkMapView (since this one possesses a property that inherits from ABFRealmMapView)
  [image]

But unfortunately this does not work ! The question is why ?????

I tried to set the delegate of the PVParkMapViewController as follows (see comented line of code below). 
[image]

But putting the delegate (i.e. uncomenting the above line) would bring the PVParkMapViewController to work correctly - but unfortunately, none of the ABFRealmMapView delegates would work anymore. So it is somehow an either or thing happening here that I don't understand.

Any help appreciated ! The goal is to have all delegates of ABFRealmMapView AND PVParkMapViewController working !

Answer (score 0):

...it took me a while - but I've found the mistake:

Indeed, setting the mapView-delegate in the PVParkMapViewController is absolutely necessary !! i.e. do the following inside - (void)viewDidLoad:

```
[self.mapView setDelegate:self];
```

or with newer writing style:

```
self.mapView.delegate = self;
```

It turns out that by doing that, all ABFRealmMapView delegates still work and they all call the external-delegates !!! In fact, it turns out that by setting the above, all ABFRealmMapView delegate-methods call the external-delegate-method implementations of PVParkMapViewController (i.e. they are deviated to the PVParkMapViewController delegates).

What had me confused was that also Annotation-Views were subject to that delegate-to-externaldelegate deviation too! And therefore (by mistake) I thought that the original delegates of ABFRealmMapView would not all work (but in reality, they were just also deviated...)!

Anyway, since both ABFRealmMapView and PVParkMap have their own Annotation-Views, you can always decide whether you want to further deviate to the externalDelegate-method or not.

Here I quickly left the initial delegate doing its thing (inside ABFRealmMapView.m)  and not further delegating to the externalDelegate by temporarily setting the externalDelegate to nil.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    // KOS: temporarily save external-delegate since for the annotationView we do not want to use the external one but the ABFClusterAnnotationView !
    id<MKMapViewDelegate>tempDelegate  = self.externalDelegate;
    // KOS: set the externalDelegate temporarily to nil in order to deviate to ABFAnnotation below....
    self.externalDelegate = nil;

    id<MKMapViewDelegate> delegate = self.externalDelegate;

    if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(mapView:viewForAnnotation:)]) {

        return [delegate mapView:mapView viewForAnnotation:annotation];
    }
    else if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[ABFAnnotation class]]) {

        // KOS: set back the externalDelegate for further use in other delegate-methods
        self.externalDelegate = tempDelegate;
        ABFAnnotation *fetchedAnnotation = (ABFAnnotation *)annotation;

        ABFClusterAnnotationView *annotationView = (ABFClusterAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:ABFAnnotationViewReuseId];

        if (!annotationView) {
            annotationView = [[ABFClusterAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:fetchedAnnotation
                                                                  reuseIdentifier:ABFAnnotationViewReuseId];
            annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
        }

        annotationView.count = fetchedAnnotation.safeObjects.count;
        annotationView.annotation = fetchedAnnotation;

        return annotationView;
    }

    // KOS: set back the externalDelegate for further use in other delegate-methods
    self.externalDelegate = tempDelegate;

    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Your "fix" works, but the expected use is that if you set a delegate for `ABFRealmMapView` and then implement one of the methods in the delegate, it will then default to using your implementation of that method versus its internal handling.

The logic is that since you implemented that method, you are taking it upon yourself to return the `viewForAnnotation:` for example versus allowing `ABFRealmMapView` to provide its default view.

If you don't implement `mapView:viewForAnnotation:` but only other delegate methods, `ABFRealmMapView` will still use the default views for annotation.

Comment: Note the line:

`if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(mapView:viewForAnnotation:)]) {`

if your delegate implements this method, then it will retrieve the view for the annotation from that implementation, versus using the implementation in the method in `ABFRealmMapView`.

Thus I don't think you need to do anything with the delegate logic.... just don't implement `mapView:viewForAnnotation:` in `PVParkMapViewController`.